# How to stop drop down menu displaying "Please Select" option when error message is displayed

Tags: php, html

let me just first say that I have tried to cut the code below as small as possible:

```
        <?php
        // required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)

        $getyear       = (isset($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['year'] : '';
        $getpass       = (isset($_POST['studentpass'])) ? $_POST['studentpass'] : '';
        $getretypepass = (isset($_POST['retypepass'])) ? $_POST['retypepass'] : '';
        $errormsg      = (isset($errormsg)) ? $errormsg : '';

        $validSubmission = isset($_POST['registerbtn']) && $_POST['year'] && $_POST['studentpass'] && $_POST['retypepass'];

        $min_year = 1;
        $max_year = 10;
        $years    = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012
        $yearHTML = '';
        $yearHTML .= '<select name="year" id="yearDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
        $yearHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($years as $year) {
            if (!$validSubmission && isset($_POST['year']) && $year == $_POST['year']) {
                $yearHTML .= "<option value='" . $year . "' selected='selected'>$year</option>" . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $yearHTML .= "<option value='" . $year . "'>$year</option>" . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        $yearHTML .= '</select>';


        if ((isset($_POST['registerbtn']))) {
            if (in_array($_POST['year'], $years) === true) {
                $getyear = (int) $_POST['year'];
            }
            $getpass       = $_POST['studentpass'];
            $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];


            if ($getyear) {
                if ($getpass) {
                    if (strlen($getpass) <= 5) {
                        $errormsg = "The Password must be a minimum of 6 characters or more";
                    } else {
                        if ($getretypepass) {
                            if ($getpass === $getretypepass) {
                                //perform 2 queries, one query contains $aliasnumrows and other contains $numrows

                                if ($aliasnumrows == 0) {
                                    if ($numrows == 0) {
                                        //perform query which contains $numrows


                                        if ($numrows == 1) {
                                            $errormsg = "<span style='color: green'>Student has been Registered</span>";

                                            $getyear = "";


                                        } else {
                                            $errormsg = "An error has occured, Student has not been Registered";

                                        }

                                    }

                                    else {
                                        $errormsg = "There is already a Student with that Username";
                                    }
                                }

                                else {
                                    $errormsg = "There is already a Student with that Alias";
                                }
                            }

                            else {
                                $errormsg = "Your Passwords did not match";
                            }
                        }

                        else {
                            $errormsg = "You must retype your Password to Register";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $errormsg = "You must enter in a Password to Register";
                }

            }

        else{
    $errormsg = "You must enter in Student's current Academic Year to Register";
    }

    }

$form = "
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Year:</td>
  <td>{$yearHTML}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input type='password' name='studentpass' value='' /></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Retype Password:</td>
  <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value='' /></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit' value='Register' name='registerbtn' /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>";

  echo $form;
```

Ok this is the issue I am having. I have a drop down menu for years and two text inputs for typing in password and re type password. Now if the user selects a year from the drop down menu and submits the form, then it displays the error message stating a password must be entered and the year drop down menu still displays the option the user has selected from the year drop down menu.

The problem I am having is that if either of these message below appear, then the drop down option goes back to displaying "Please Select". My question is that how can I stop the drop down menu going back to the "Please Select" option when the following error messages appear?

```
$errormsg = "There is already a Student with that Username";
$errormsg = "There is already a Student with that Alias";
$errormsg = "Your Passwords did not match";
$errormsg = "You must retype your Password to Register";
```

The line of code I believe needs changing is here:

```
    $validSubmission = isset($_POST['registerbtn']) && $_POST['year'] && $_POST['studentpass'] && $_POST['retypepass'];
```

Comment: Your code contains a LOT of logic that is extremely hard to follow (not to mention inconvenient when someone has more than one error since it will only show one of them and they will have to submit the form again). When I validate forms, I add all my errors to an array then loop through them to display them back to the user.

Comment: @Mike Yeah that is one improvement I can make. To be honest I am doing back end so is it up to me to determine that or up to the person doing the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is this:

```
// This is just a suggestion, but I would set these to null instead of an empty string:
    $getyear       = (isset($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['year'] : null;
    $getpass       = (isset($_POST['studentpass'])) ? $_POST['studentpass'] : null;
    $getretypepass = (isset($_POST['retypepass'])) ? $_POST['retypepass'] : null;
    $errormsg      = (isset($errormsg)) ? $errormsg : null;
// You have already defined these, so no need to use $_POST here
// Also, I like to compare it to an actual value rather than just doing if ($variable)
// to avoid unforseen circumstances. Note, isset() returns false if $var == null.
$validSubmission = (isset($_POST['registerbtn']) && isset($getyear) && isset($getpass) && isset($getretypepass));
```

Then I think you've got your logic backwards later on:

```
    foreach ($years as $year) {
        if ($validSubmission && $year == $getyear) {
            $yearHTML .= "<option value='" . $year . "' selected='selected'>$year</option>" . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $yearHTML .= "<option value='" . $year . "'>$year</option>" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe he is using $validSubmission to validate that the values are not "falsey", not if they are set.

Comment: True, I think maybe his logic is backwards and he is inverting his check on `$validSubmission` later.

Comment: Do I need to get rid of the isset()'s at the top of the script which I already have and include the isset in the `$validSubmiision` as you mentioned?

Comment: Ah no its fine, I just included the code you stated and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Can I ask one little question then. IF the user submits and it is successful, then how do I get the drop down menus to then display "Please Select"? As that now I have changed the code, it means now that "please Select" option is not displayed after success while in my old code it did do it

Comment: @Mike when this message appears when the form is completed correctly `$errormsg = "<span style='color: green'>Student has been Registered</span>";`

Comment: @user1881090 you would need to change your whole logic to do that. Get rid of that huge block of nested `if`/`else` and use an array, check for an error at the end and put the drop down box after that, not before it.

Answer (score 1):

When repopulating the Year dropdown, you probably don't actually care if  any part of the submission is valid or not, you just want to repopulate it regardless. Simply drop the logic for that.

```
foreach ($years as $year) {
    if (isset($_POST['year']) && $year == $_POST['year']) {
        $yearHTML .= "<option value='" . $year . "' selected='selected'>$year</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $yearHTML .= "<option value='" . $year . "'>$year</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. This is probably a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are posting back to the server, and the server is re-rendering the page. In order to do this *properly* and in a way that will work across all browsers, you would need to echo the $_POST results (after properly escaping them) back into the input elements.

Similarly, you'd need to use the $_POST value for the select box to determine which `option` tag should have its `selected="selected"` attribute set.